# Barely any commands work, no module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: apt, python, kernel-modules, path

I don't know what I've done but basic commands like "ls" and "sudo" no longer work and now throw me this error message.

```
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from apport.report import Report
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
import apport.fileutils
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Please help, I'm crying, I have a deadline tomorrow.

Should I just do a fresh install of Ubuntu but keep the files?

Comment: Welcome! After what command the error shows?

Comment: Let us start with the basics. does `cd /bin` work or give an error? If it works does `cd /bin ; echo ls*` give one or more words of output including `ls`, or does it only give `ls*` back?

Comment: Lots of different commands all bring the same error (at least the same as far as I can tell with a quick skim-read). Commands like "sudo", "ls", "dpkg" but commands like "cd" and "pwd" work fine

Comment: @icarus Hi Icarus, both of those commands work and the second one prints out more than just ls it prints out lsblk and lsmod too

Comment: Great. Does `/bin/ls -l /bin/ls` give you a long listing of the 'ls program or an error? If it works then run `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH` and see if `ls` and `sudo` are now working.

Comment: It doesn't exactly give me a long listing but it doesn't give me an error, it says -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 133792 Jan 18  2018 /bin/ls, ls and sudo now work!!

Comment: @icarus you are a god-send, I removed some very silly edits to my .bashrc and everything seems to be okay now? (fingers crossed) thank-you so much

Comment: @Retsek Good luck with the thing you had a deadline for!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We did some debugging with the OP.

1. `cd /bin`
   This worked,so we knew /bin had not been deleted
2. `cd /bin; echo ls*` This produced "ls lsblk lsmod" rather than "ls*" so we knew there were at least 3 files in /bin
3. `/bin/ls -l /bin/ls` This produced "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 133792 Jan 18 2018 /bin/ls" so it wasn't a matter of execute permissions being removed.
4. `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH` This creates a sane couple of places to look for commands, and now `ls` and `sudo` are working again.

Conclusion: The `PATH` variable had become corrupted, and hence bash couldn't find anything. Using step by step debugging starting with just builtin commands (`cd` and `echo`) this was diagnosed quickly. Hopefully the OP has dried their tears and is all smiles again.

The OP has just commented that they have "removed some very silly edits to my .bashrc and everything seems to be okay".

Comment: You are a Unix detective, genius and saint. Thank-you for blessing me with your troubleshooting <3

Comment: You are not the first person to have mangled the `PATH`.  It was my first thought, too.  The difference here is that in an attempt at user-friendliness Ubuntu adds an extension to the Bourne Again shell that runs another program when a command is not found, instead of printing a short "command not found" message.  When that program fails, as here, _its_ error messages are vastly _less_ user-friendly than the vanilla "command not found" message.  What icarus has not covered is repairing the command-not-found system, to stop the utility program from failing.

Comment: … as it still is at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/568967/5132 . (-:

Comment: I was once really surprised to find that some commands could run faster than a command that wasn't found.  That drove me nuts for a few days.  Thanks Ubuntu!